# ASP NET how to send event from ASPX to ASCX

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I got some legacy sitecore asp net application.
And I find out that on layout (aspx) i have ImageButton control that should change site language.

```
    protected void btnLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton flag = (ImageButton)sender;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("") == false)
        {
           UserContext.CurrentCulture = LanguageManager.GetLanguage(flag.CommandArgument);                     
        }
        else
        {
            SC.Context.Language = LanguageManager.GetLanguage(flag.CommandArgument);
        }
    }
```

But I have a lot of controls that should be translated after this event would called. By asp net page life style process it is not good behavior but anyway I need to do something with it. What is the best way to do it in my case and how it should be done in correct way?

Comment: The quickest way that comes to mind is to save the language in the Session and access it from the various controls (they should all get a page load event when the main page is posted back, so you can check in there).

Comment: Thanks. yes it is idea. But what about right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alistair Deneys documented how to use events to allow components to communicate with each other. It's worth being aware of this mechanism, take a look at Alistair's post [Decoupling Through the Sitecore Event Pool](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/decoupling-through-the-sitecore-event-pool/).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Sitecore application then just let Sitecore handle it, change your image button to a regular image with a hyperlink and pass in the language parameter (use the LinkManager):

`/en-CA/some-folder/some-page.aspx`

`/some-folder/some-page.aspx?sc_lang=en-CA`

You can then set the system culture based on `Sitecore.Context.Lanaguge`

Some useful [info in this post](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/multiple-languages-in-sitecore/), see the comments as well.